# project reference in typescript not working

Tags: typescript

im trying to use typescript project refence and it does not seem to work
i use node 14.15.4 and typescript 4.5.5 ide webstorm
i want to refrence the code from common in server

i have 2 folders

```
 1 - to_ref
           code
              x.ts
           tsconfig.json
    
    2 - runner
           code
              run.ts
           tsconfig.json   
 3 - base_config
           tsconfig.json
```

## to_ref:

tsconfig.json:

```
  {
      extends: ../base_config/tsconfig.json
    },
    complierOptions: {
        composite:true,
        rootDir: .
        outDir: ./dist
    }

}
```

## x.ts:

```
export function f(){
return 'x';
}
```

## runner:

run.ts:

```
import {f} from "../to_ref/code/x";

f();
```

## tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      extends: ../base_config/tsconfig.json
    },
    complierOptions: {
        composite:true,
        rootDir: .
        outDir: ./dist
    },
    refernces: [
    {
      path: ../to_ref
    }
]

}
```

## base_config/tsconfig:

```
{
 complierOptions: {
 target: ES2022,
exprimentalDecorators: true,
emitDecoratorsMetadata: true,
module: commonjs,
moduleResuyltion: node,
strict: true
composite: true,
declaration: true
}
}
```

i ran npx run tsc in to_ref folder
i ran npx run tsc --build in runner folder

when i try to run with nodejs the runner i get
MODULE_NOT_FOUND ../to_ref/src/x

can someone help?

Comment: Change `import {f} from "../to_ref/src/x"` to `import {f} from "../to_ref/code/x"`?

Comment: i got the folder name incorrect. i fix the name in the question

Comment: it still not working... please help

Comment: Seems like you need to move two directories up, change `import {f} from "../to_ref/code/x"` to `import {f} from "../../to_ref/code/x"`

Comment: thanks for the reply... its not working